# @TestConfiguration for Embedded Redis, same Redis Server for all Test classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-boot-test

I use a [Embedded Redis](https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis) for integration testing. I set up my tests with Redis according to following article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-embedded-redis.

The problem is, if I want to use the @TestConfiguration with several test classes, I get errors because @PreDestroy is not called. The Embedded Redis is created new each time and is not shared between the test classes. It is therefore tried every time to create a new Redis Sserver on the same port, which leads to the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRedisConfiguration': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
```

When I add the @DirtiesContext to all test classes I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@255e5e2e has been closed already
```

Is there a way to use the same Embedded Redis for all my test classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the EmbeddedRedis in a method with `@BeforeClass` annotation. This will restrict your redis cache construction for the entire Test Class once.

Comment: In this case, however, I would have to start and stop redis in every test class. Is there no way to keep this central?

Comment: You can create a TestSuite, and do initialization there.

Answer (score 0):

resolved the same issue by adding custom annotation and annotating each test class with it. here is an example in kotlin:

```
@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationRedisConfiguration(
    @Value("\${spring.redis.port}") redisPort: Int
) {
    private val redisServer: RedisServer = RedisServer(redisPort)

    @PostConstruct
    fun postConstruct() = redisServer.start()

    @PreDestroy
    fun preDestroy() = redisServer.stop()
}

@SpringBootTest(
    classes = [IntegrationRedisConfiguration::class]
)
annotation class IntegrationTest

@IntegrationTest
class Service1Spec : FunSpec() { ... }

@IntegrationTest
class Service2Spec : FunSpec() { ... }
```